# How do I get error messages from nosetests

Tags: python, nose

The `nosetest` command is failing with no messages.  If I cd to my home directory I get the message I would expect:

```sh
(base) raysalemi@RayProMac ~ % nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

But if I cd to my tests directory I get this:

```sh
/Users/raysalemi/repos/pyuvm/tests/nosetests
(base) raysalemi@RayProMac nosetests % ls
__pycache__         pyuvm_unittest.py       test_05_base_classes.py     test_06_reporting_classes.py
(base) raysalemi@RayProMac nosetests % nosetests
(base) raysalemi@RayProMac nosetests % echo $?
1
```

This has been running for months so I'm not certain of the change, but I can't get an error message to check, only the exit status.

Suggestions?

Comment: "Ran 0 tests" should not be expected ...

Comment: Make sure nothing is calling `os.exit` or `os.kill` or similar ... are you testing something that uses C code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to CD to my test directory and run python with the unittest module on the same command line:

```sh
(base) raysalemi@RayProMac nosetests % python -m unittest

No module named 'copyz'
No module named 'copyz'
EE
```

I had accidentally stuck a `z` into my code and the import was failing. The only way to get that message was to use `unittest` directly.